# How to use a loop to query a Product2 list from a QuoteLineItem list?

Tags: apex, controller, loop

I have no idea why this isn't working, some help would be greatly apprectiated! Here is my loop:

```
for(integer i = 0; i < myQuote.LineItemCount; i++) {
        prod.add([select id from Product2 where id=:qli.get(i).Product2Id]);
}
```

EDIT: prod is a Product2 List and qli is a QuoteLineItem List btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **you are trying to put a list (the query result) inside another list (prod)**. You should get only one object from the list to assign it into `prod` using the `.add` method.

Secondly, you are using a query inside a for, which isn't optimized at all, and [might get you into trouble](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) if your code somehow needs to process a large amount of items.

You should make the query outside the for scope, and inside of it assign to the list the Product2 objects that you want (using conditional structures).

Here is an example:

```
trigger MyTriggerName on MyObject__c (after insert, before update)
{
    // this is a special bool that triggers have
    // to specify when to run code. Everything in this scope
    // will run only when the trigger is called in an object update
    if (Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        // you query for related information in your database
        List<MyOtherObject__c> moList = [SELECT Id, Name, CustomField__c, AnotherCustomField__c FROM MyOtherObject__c WHERE CustomField__c IN :Trigger.new];

        // you create a list to store records that will be updated
        List<MyOtherObject__c> updatedMos = new List<MyOtherObject__c>();

        // you can create another list for MyObject__c if you want to update
        // both objects. It all depends on what you in your code below.

        for (MyOtherObject__c mo : moList)
        {
            for (MyObject__c obj : Trigger.new)
            {
                // your conditional goes here
                // if, for example, MyOtherObject has a CustomField that
                // contains an ID referencing to an object MyObject, and
                // you want to check if the object is refering a object
                // you do something like this
                if (mo.CustomField__c == obj.Id)
                {
                    // do your stuff here, either to 'mo' or 'obj'
                    mo.AnotherCustomField__c = 'bananas';
                    // and then add the updated object to the list
                    updatedMos.add(mo);
                }
            }
        }

        // if you update a MyOtherObject__c or MyObject__c you
        // should update your database by doing this
        if (updatedMos.size() > 0)
        {
            update updatedMos;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: added code for exemplification.

Comment: may I ask how to do this? I am relatively new to Apex and don't really know all the conventions for the language.

Comment: Check my post for an example. It has some good approaches. ;)